# Is it possible to python-pyqgis standalone .exe in different computers?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, qgis

I have created one standalone exe in python using pyqgis libraries. It's running perfectly in my computer. But it's failing to run in different computers and not able to import qgis libraries.

Is it supposed to be like that?

Or do I need to install qgis in others computers too?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a QGIS based application, the machine will need QGIS to run.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications) (emphasys mine):

> When deploying custom applications using PyQGIS, there are usually two possibilities:
>
> - **require user to install QGIS on his platform prior to installing your application**. The application installer should look for default locations of QGIS libraries and allow user to set the path if not found. This approach has the advantage of being simpler, however it requires user to do more steps.
> - **package QGIS together with your application**. Releasing the application may be more challenging and the package will be larger, but the user will be saved from the burden of downloading and installing additional pieces of software.